# add data to csv column wise using pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, pandas

I have some csv files and I want to copy a specific column from all of them and save it in a new csv file column wise.But the following code add them in a single column.

Also in total I have to go through almost 20M data so I don't want to store them in a single dataframe and save them in last.

Here is my code:

```
import os 
import glob
import pandas as pd
k= glob.glob("*.csv")
colu="Close"
file="merged.csv"
temp_dirr="./temp/"
if not os.path.exists(temp_dirr):
    os.makedirs(temp_dirr)

filename=temp_dirr+file

df=pd.read_csv(k[0])[colu].dropna()
df.to_csv(filename,header=False,index=False)
for i in k[1:]:
    df=pd.read_csv(i)[colu].dropna()
    df.to_csv(filename,mode="a",header=False,index=False)
```

and here is the output `merged.csv` file

`23.6
1065
23.45
1150
172.7
11098
11443.3`

But i want the output file to be like this

`23.6    172.7
1065    11098
23.45   11443.3
1150`

Here the folder has 2 csv files and the two columns are for for the `"close"` column of those 2 files. So how to add them columnwise?

Comment: how do you want to merge your files? For example 1st row from each file should "land" in the first row of the result file - it could work if you wouldn't use `.dropna()`. If not please clarify how do you want to join your data from different files

Comment: the `"close"` is the 9th column of those csv file and I need this column. Now 9th column form 1st file land in 1st column of result csv file, 9th column from 2nd file land in 2nd column of result and so on

Comment: i'm asking about __rows__... for example in first file 9-th column has those values: `1,2,NaN,3,4` and file2 has: `11,NaN,22,33,NaN` - how your result file should look like?

Comment: well the columns are unequal, there may be NaN values but they are all at the end. so they will fill up the column from row 1 like say col 1 `1,2 ,3` and col2 `1,2,3,4,5` (and last 2 line of col 1 will just be blank)

Answer (score 1):

you can do it this way:

```
def get_merged_csv(flist, **kwargs):
    return pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, **kwargs) for f in flist], axis=1)

fmask = '*.csv'
# column numbers are starting from 0, so 9th column has index 8 
df = get_merged_csv(glob.glob(fmask), usecols=[8])
df.to_csv(filename,mode="a",header=False,index=False)
```

Comment: how long this single dataframe can hold? beacuse I have 2K files each with almost 5K lines of data

Comment: it depends on your memory and whether you are using 32-bit or 64-bit systems/Python/etc. Usually i'm working with 10-14GB data frames on my notebook (RAM 16GB, Windows 7 64-bit, Python 3.5 64-bit) - without any issues. So your 20MB shouldn't be a problem at all even on 32-bit system with 3.5 GB RAM limitation

Comment: Its not 20MB, its 20 million

Comment: what is the summary size of all your files?

Comment: it should be `usecols` - i've updated my answer correspondingly

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to do this using Pythond, but in R, it is very easy.

Merge all columns in File1 and Column12 in File2.

```
import pandas as pd
file1 = pd.read_table('C:\\Users\Users\\your_path_here\\Book1.csv', delimiter=',', header=None)
file2 = pd.read_table('C:\\Users\\Users\\your_path_here\\Book2.csv', delimiter=',', header=None)
file2_short = file2.ix[:,12:13]

#print (file2_short)
frames=[file1, file2_short]
new = pd.concat(frames)
new.to_csv('C:\\Users\\your_path_here\\newfile.csv')
```